# Reference request for the generating function $\frac{x^k}{1-x-x^2-\cdots-x^k-x^{k+1}}$ of generalized $k$-step Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to find a reference
for the generating function $\frac{x^k}{1-x-x^2-\cdots-x^k-x^{k+1}}$ of generalized $k$-step Fibonacci numbers. It looks like it is a kind of folklore result.

I found some related expressions on page 309 in Arndt's [book](https://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf) and on page 42 of [Flajolet-Sedgewick](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf), but I wonder who was really the first to derive this expression ?

Comment: It’s not hard to prove. It depends on $F_0,F_1,\dots,F_{k-1}.$

Comment: Yes, sure. I know how to prove it. I'm asking for some canonical reference.

Comment: I’ve never seen it particularly proven, only seen the more general results. But it hardly belongs in “folklore” level when it is easily derived from proven theorems.

Comment: You can instead find a reference that the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers is $x^2/(1-x-x^2)$ (should be one on Wikipedia), and then say "by an analogous argument, the generating function for the $k$-step numbers is...".